# Is every 2-sided ideal in a C*-algebra hereditary?

Tags: c-star-algebras, ideals

If $A$ is a C*-algebra, we say that a subset $I\subseteq A$ is hereditary if
$$
  0\leq x \leq y \in I \Rightarrow x\in I.
  $$
It is is well known that closed 2-sided ideals are hereditary.

Would it also be true for arbitrary 2-sided ideals?  What about self-adjoint 2-sided ideals?

Comment: There are often big families of non-closed ideals which are hereditary though, of which the best known is the Pedersen ideal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Take $A = C[0,1]$ and let $I$ be the (unclosed) ideal generated by the function $f(t) = t$. This ideal is self-adjoint, but it does not contain the function $g(t) = t\sin^2(\frac{1}{t})$, so it is not hereditary. (Example II.5.2.1 (iii) in Bruce Blackadar's fantastic book [*Operator Algebras: Theory of C${}^*$-Algebras and von Neumann Algebras*](https://packpages.unr.edu/media/1224/cycr.pdf).)

Comment: (My first example, which everyone seemed to like, was actually not correct.)

Comment: Regarding your 1st example I am puzzled.  It seems to me that $g=fh$, there, implied that $h$ is constant  equal to one on $[0,1/2]$ which is impossible.  Can you give me a hint why this is wrong?

Comment: Yeah, okay. In that example I was correct in saying that $g$ is neither a scalar multiple of $f$ nor of the form $fh$ for some $h \in A$ $\ldots$ however, it is a sum of such things. So it does belong to the ideal generated by $f$.